# Custom Saltstack Python module function accesible in pillar sls file

Tags: salt-stack

I am having some data loaded inside of my pillar file `configuration.sls` which is using Jinja templating. I would like to do some additional processing on part of that data (dictionary structure) before saving as pillar. The additional processing is a bit complicated to be written in Jinja so I would like to do such additional processing in some Python function and be able to call that function like salt module.

I know I can define my own module inside of `_modules` called `example.py` in which I can have defined function called `get_processed_data(data)` and in state file call it in Jinja like:

```
 {% set data_to_save = salt.example.get_processed_data(data) %}
```

But I am unable to do such thing in pillar `configurations.sls` file. When I try, pillar renders with error that it does not know `example`. Is there any approach how to do such thing?

I am aware about `ext_pillars`, but as far as I know, these are used like pillar file written in Python. What I am interested in, is to be able to create just simple function, which could be called in pillar file. And also I would guess it should be doable somehow, because in pillar it is possible to call `salt.file.find()`, where `file` is also a module (built in, but still).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since pillar is rendered on the master you need to make sure the module is synced to the master.

when you sync using `salt <minion> saltutil.sync_modules` you are syncing to the minion. to sync to the master use `salt-run saltutil.sync_modules`

see https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.saltutil.html#salt.runners.saltutil.sync_modules

everything else will be the same.